# MS Soap Toolkit v3.0, Windows Server 2003 & Lotus Domino 7

Tags: web-services, soap, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a Lotusscript agent calling a webservice.  This works when triggered using a Notes Client (notes 7, windows 7) with Microsoft Soap Toolkit v3.0 installed, but does not work when scheduled to run on the server (Lotus Domino 7.0.3) with the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit v3.0 installed.

Things to note:

- Runtime security set to 3 on the agent.
- Agent is signed and saved using as ID with full rights to the server.

The error being received is then the following line of code is run.  This suggests to me that the Toolkit is not installed, or that is cannot be invoked.

```
    Set Client =CreateObject("MSOSOAP.SoapClient30")
```

I have found reference from Microsoft ([Support for SOAP Toolkit Versions 2.0 and 3.0 on Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811215)) that recommends against using the toolkit for a windows 2003 Server as it is no longer supported - neither is Notes 7 so this is not a concern.  They also state that 'SOAP Toolkit 3.0 server components and SOAP Toolkit ISAPI Listener are not supported on the Windows Server 2003 operating system.' - however this also is not a concern as I don't *think* we are using the server components of the toolkit?

The agent errors with the generic message "Error 208 Cannot create automation object".

If I can't use the Microsoft Soap Toolkit v3.0, then what would be the simplest method to invoke the webservice using lotusscript in a scheduled agent, bearing in mind the outdated technology being used?

Comment: You say that you have it working from a client on Windows 7. Have you tried going to the server machine, launching the client there (assuming it is installed, which is often the case), and running the agent manually in that environment? That should help you determine whether the SOAP Toolkit is properly installed, registered, and working on the Win2003 machine.

Comment: Hey @RichardSchwartz - thanks for your note. I just managed to get access to the server.  Can't run the agent manually as the client is not installed on the server, and can't be installed on the server.  All I can see is that the SOAP Toolkit is installed.

Comment: Can you write a VBScript program to test the toolkit and run that on the server?

Comment: We have very limited access to the server, so not really.  This process is going to be run manually for now as it works when run from a client, and will be revisited when the Domino servers are upgraded.  Tks for your assistance anyhow.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz - it has been solved!  If I had been able to do your troubleshooting then it would have picked up the issue.  Worked it out when the SOAP toolkit was installed on another machine.  See below.

Answer (score 1):

For an unknown reason, the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit was installed in the registry on some machines as both MSOSOAP.SoapClient30 AND MSSOAP.SoapClient30, and on other machines (the Windows Server 2003 and another desktop) as MSSOAP.SoapClient30 only.  I have no idea why, and am delighted that I worked this out.  OMFG.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the web service even without using the MSSOAP client. You can consume the web service using the "Web Service Consumer" design element in the Lotus Domino Designer Client.